# Marginalising probability distribution

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, marginal-distribution

I am reading a book on probability theory and there is an example to denote conditional independence. A joint distribution is given as follows

$$
p(a, b, c) = p(a) p(b) p(c|a,b)
$$

Now, assuming none of the variables are observed, the point is to show $a$ and $b$ are conditionally independent. They marginalise over $c$ to get

$$
p(a, b) = p(a) p(b)
$$

Is this because when you sum over $c$, $p(c|a, b)$ is a valid distribution and sums to 1?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general,

$$f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z) = f_{Z\mid X,Y}(z \mid x,y)\cdot f_{X,Y}(x,y) 
= f_{Z\mid X,Y}(z \mid x,y)\cdot f_{Y\mid X}(y \mid x)\cdot f_X(x).$$

In your instance, you are told that for your particular variables

$$f_{X,Y,Z}(x,y,z)  
= f_{Z\mid X,Y}(z \mid x,y)\cdot f_{X}(x)\cdot f_Y(y)$$

and so

$$f_{X,Y}(x,y) = f_{X}(x)\cdot f_Y(y),$$

that is, $X$ and $Y$ are *unconditionally* independent, not conditionally
independent as your book claims.

To answer your specific questions

- Yes, $p(c\mid a,b)$ is a valid distribution and so $\sum_c p(c \mid a,b) = 1$.
- Marginalizing $p(a,b,c)$ with respect to $c$ *always*
  gives $\sum_c p(a,b,c) = p(a,b).$

  In your special case, $p(a,b,c)$ happens
  to equal $p(a)p(b)p(c\mid a,b)$ and so marginalizing $p(a,b,c)$ expressed
  in the form $p(a)p(b)p(c\mid a,b)$  is the same as marginalizing $p(c\mid a,b)$ after pulling $p(a)p(b)$
  out of the sum as a constant not depending on $c$. Thus we are left with
  $$p(a,b) = p(a)p(b)$$ which shows that $a$ and $b$ are *unconditionally*
  independent variables.

  *Conditional* independence would require something like $p(a,b\mid c) = p(a\mid c)p(b\mid c)$ to hold, and this may or may not be true in this particular
  instance: there is not enough information to make a determination.
- Note that it *is* possible for variables to be unconditionally
  independent but conditionally dependent.  A standard example is that
  of *Poisson splitting:*  Color each arrival in a Poisson process 
  with arrival rate $\lambda$ as red or blue
  with probabilities $p$ and $1-p$ and independently of all other colorings.
  Then the red arrivals and blue arrivals are independent Poisson processes
  with arrival rates $\lambda p$ and $\lambda(1-p)$ respectively.  In
  particular, the number of red arrivals in $(0,T]$ and the number of blue arrivals
  in $(0,T]$ are independent Poisson random variables with parameters
  $\lambda pT$ and $\lambda(1-p)T$ respectively, **but** *conditioned*
  on a *total* number of $N$ arrivals in $(0,T]$, the numbers of red and
  blue arrivals are *dependent* binomial random variables with parameters
  $(N,p)$ and $(N,(1-p))$ respectively: dependent because their sum must equal $N$.