# Poisson arrival

Tags: poisson-distribution, poisson-process

Users arrive according to Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. If every third user is removed, then do the remaining users form a Poisson process with rate $2\lambda/3$?
If every other user is removed, then do the remaining users form a Poisson process with rate $\lambda/2$? and so on..?

Comment: It depends on how the removal occurs: are you saying each user is removed independently with probability $1/3$ or that literally every third user is systematically removed?  If the latter is the case, then consider what that does to the patterns of inter-arrival times and recall that in a Poisson process the inter-arrival times must be independent.

Comment: I am saying that every other user is removed.

Comment: I believe the resulting process will not be Poisson after doing some research. Can anyone please verify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, *deterministic* deletion of arrivals (such as "delete every third arrival") does not leave a Poisson process, but *random* deletion does, e.g. for every
arrival, make a decision (independent of all past and future decisions) to
delete with probability $\frac{1}{3}$ and to not delete with probability $\frac 23$.
Then what is left after such random deletions *is* a Poisson process with rate
$\frac{2\lambda}{3}$.  Read, for example, the last paragraph of [this answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/90437/6633).

Answer (score 3):

whuber pretty much covered it already in his comment, but I'll give a slightly different way of thinking about it. I'll try to come back with a slightly longer one soon

Short answer:

The interarrival time is now exponential($\lambda$) for some users and Gamma(2,$\lambda$) for others (time to removed user, plus time from removed user to next user). It's therefore not a Poisson process.

[If the removals were random rather than every third user, however, it would be a Poisson process.]